# Property 'json' does not exist on type 'HttpResponse<any>'

Tags: angular, httpresponse, angular-http

`HttpResponse` is a generic class in `@angular/common/http`, so I need to mention a type e.g. `HttpResponse<T>` (replace 'T' with data type). Now that I am replacing old angular code from this:

```
.map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

to this:

```
.map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => res.json());
```

as class `Response` is deprecated (**whole package @angular/http is deprecated**). But this is giving me an error as below:

`Property 'json' does not exist on type 'HttpResponse<any>'.`

So I believe I have to change the type, but to what? Moreover, writing it like that is correct or not?

Comment: The httpClient parses your JSON to an object so this line is not needed `.map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => res.json());`

Comment: @AJT_82 : then can you please tell me, where and how to use `HttpResponse` in angular, as I haven't got any info regarding its usage on internet, just looking at docs don't give much idea

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you are looking to type your data, that is done like `return this.httpClient.get<MyType>(.....)` https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response

Comment: try res.body to get the data inside body of the response. refer this link for documentation https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse